# Using sum within google spreadsheet query results in the word "sum" in many cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get the some of all values in row B that contain a certain value in row A. Pretty simple problem I guess.

Here is my query:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!$A$16:D, "Select sum(D) Where C contains '"&C5&"' ", -1)
```

But what that gives me is the actual word "sum" in all the fields where C contains the value.
So I get a lot of "sum" in almost all my rows.
Did the "sum" statement change for queries in google spreadsheets?

Comment: Also "count(A)" does not work either and just gives me the actual word "count" as a result.

Comment: Removed the `mysql` tag. I don't see the context for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you are using more than one `query` formula: apparently there is a column with `query`, each referring to a cell such as C5. In this case there is no room for column label "sum" that the formula wants to insert: the output must be a single cell. Solution: change the column label to empty string with `label sum(D) ''`.

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!$A$16:D, "Select sum(D) Where C contains '"&C5&"' label sum(D) ''", -1)
```

Comment: Ok this works!
But could you please elaborate on how this works exactly? What does "label" do? Why are there two ' ' at the end of the query?
Thanks!

Comment: Each column of the output has a "name", which comes either from header row of your data or from the query string, e.g., sum. But these names can be changed: `label sum(D) 'blah'` at the end changes the label of that column to "blah". So, `label sum(D) ''` changes it to empty string. Single quotes are simply delimiters of strings within the double-quoted query string.